# Linear regression model in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a linear regression prbolem at hand to solve, and I have found that this Matlab function `mdl = fitlm(X, y)` can do that. Then the new problem occured: after knowing about the usage of this function, I can't use this function in my `Matlab R2013a`. It always says `Undefined function or variable 'fitlm'`.

I think this may be due to some settings having not been done, but I am not familiar with Matlab. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `fitlm()` is available in R2013a, unfortunately. You can check if you have the Statistics Toolbox by running the `ver` command, and use the `exist` command to check if `fitlm()` is available:

```
>> ver
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
MATLAB Version: 8.0.0.783 (R2012b)
...
Stateflow                                             Version 8.0        (R2012b)
Statistics Toolbox                                    Version 8.1        (R2012b)
Symbolic Math Toolbox                                 Version 5.9        (R2012b)
...

>> exist fitlm
ans =
     0
```

That said, if `fitlm()` isn't available, try using the `LinearModel.fit` instead: http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/linearmodel.fit.html

It looks like it might do exactly what you need!

Answer (score 1):

`polyfit` with `n=1` should do the trick.

```
p = polyfit(x,y,1);
```